# Recommend a good db4o viewer

Tags: .net, nosql, db4o, object-oriented-database

I'm playing around with db4o, and I have the Object Manager viewer thingy for Visual Studio.  It seems okay, but not exactly on par with tools like HeidiSQL/SQL Studio/etc., not to mention that it locks the db4o file--I can't use my db4o app and Object Manager at the same time.

Maybe I'm using it wrong, but regardless, I'd like to know what else is out there.  What tools would you recommend for looking at and manipulating db4o files?

UPDATE: I've been using LINQPad.  There is some yak-shaving involved, but it's working pretty well.  It still leaves a lot to be desired in terms of the functionality available in applications like HeidiSQL/SQL Studio/etc., but it's a start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you use [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) as a first start.

Gamlor has [a great tutorial on how to use LINQPad with db4o](http://www.gamlor.info/wordpress/?p=949). You'll need to modify that a bit so you use client-server access (thus not locking your db).

I don't want to re-post his code here, because I think it's pointless and he's also a user here, don't wanna win his laurels.

For me, LINQPad seems to be the best approach, also because I can use it on my server, where I'd be having trouble with OME for obvious reasons.

Comment: I didn't even think about LINQPad in that context: good call.

Comment: Yes, LINQPad isn't a bad choice. But without the domain-classes (or in the Java world) it's useless. So the search for a excellent ad hoc query/diagnostic tool for db4o goes on.

Comment: But is that really a common scenario? I mean, you typically will have the model binaries at hand, won't you?

Comment: Yes, you normally have the model binaries around. But would it be easier if you don't have to setup LINQPad?

Comment: Yeah it would be.  Do you know of something that does that? :)

Comment: Just wanna note that I've created a db4o driver for LINQPad: http://www.gamlor.info/wordpress/2011/04/linqpad-db4o-driver-feature-overview/

Comment: what about for Java, is there something like LINQPad?

Answer (score 5):

We have discussed integrating some kind of "interactive LINQ query" into Object Manager (.Net of course :).

If you think this would be a nice feature, please vote in the issue [here](http://tracker.db4o.com/browse/OMN-146).

Also, any input on how to improve Object Manager is welcome.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.  Maybe a LINQPad plugin would be easier?  Also, what about locking the db4o file when using OM?  That can be very frustrating.

Comment: Not locking the file can lead to database corruption. The solution (IMHO) is to use it in C/S mode (but your app needs to use the same mode of course)

Regarding a LINQPad plugin it may have some potential issues (for instance licensing). To be honest, I am not used to LINQPad.

Comment: I would like it if Object Manager wasn't (only) a Visual Studio plugin. Visual Studio Express does not support add-ins, so unless I pay for Visual Studio I can't browse my database. A standalone version of Object Manager, and/or one that integrates with MonoDevelop would be very handy.

Answer (score 3):

Me too. I've been using DB4O for a few years, and have found the Object Manager clumsy, and often buggy (sometimes it won't open my large DB4O database at all).

I know of no alternatives, unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe we should write one then, if there really aren't any good alternatives?

Comment: Sounds good to me. Send me a patch for that. :-)

Comment: Sorry, when I said "we", I really meant "you" :-P

Comment: Yep, so when I read "we", I figured it meant "you", Mr. Groves. ;-)
As for me, I've got my hands full at the moment.

Comment: Well, if I still don't hear of any alternatives, I'll eventually start a project, which you will be welcome to participate in should your hands get freed up :)

Comment: Fair enough. Email me if you start: judahgabriel at gmail