# Is anyone aware of an Object Manager Enterprise plugin for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, db4o

I'm using DB4O on a new project I'm playing with and it would help me no end if I was able to use the Object Manager Enterprise utility.  I understand it's only available as a VS plugin, so does anyone know whether such a plugin is / will be available for Visual Studio 2010, or is there another way to get the utility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there's no Object Manager version available for Visual Studio 2010. =(

A few suggestions for alternatives:

- When you still have Visual Studio 2008 or 2005 installed, you can use the existing Object Manager for these versions.
- You can use LINQPad for db4o as suggested [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411424/recommend-a-good-db4o-viewer/2417204#2417204). However this only works together when you load your domain model into LINQPad
- You could use the Object Manager plugin for Eclipse. This version is distributed with the Java-version of db4o. So you need to download Eclipse and the java-db4o distribution. However this version of the Object Manager doesn't fully understand the .NET types, so some object are correctly displayed.

Answer (score 3):

OME will be available for VS2010 when we introduce .Net 4.0 support.

Meanwhile you can try to install the OME that comes with db4o .Net 3.5 package and change the configuration file OMAddin.AddIn from "%mydocuments%\Visual Studio 2008\Addins\" to "%mydocuments%\Visual Studio 2010\Addins\" (if this folder doesn't exist just create it)

Then, open OMAddin.AddIn and change the line:

<Version>9.0</Version>

to

<Version>10.0</Version>

Now after starting VS 2010 OME should work and you should be able to see its toolbar (I have this procedure with VS 2010 beta2 and it worked).

Best

Adriano

Comment: As of today (Nov/07/2010) OME is already available for VS2010 (downloadable with db4o for .NET 4.0)