# Does db4o have any Management studio like app for adhoc querying?

Tags: c#, db4o

Does db4o have any Management studio like app for adhoc querying? ObjectManager Enterprise I think is for development only since its embedded in either in visual studio or eclipse.. Is there any independent or separate app for browsing/manipulating its data directly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommend a good db4o viewer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411424/recommend-a-good-db4o-viewer)